# spaCy's regex is different to Python's regex

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I have the following text

```
text = 'Monday to Friday 12 midnight to 5am 30% . Midnight Friday to 6am Saturday 30% . 9pm Saturday to Midnight Saturday 25% . Midnight Saturday to 6am Sunday 100% . 6am Sunday to 9pm Sunday 50%'
```

When I used *normal* regex, I obtained the following

```
import re
regex = '\d{1}[a|p]m'
re.findall(regex, text)

# Returned:
['5am', '6am', '9pm', '6am', '6am', '6pm']
```

However, when I used the same `regex` in spaCy, I got nothing back

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'TEXT': {'REGEX': '\d{1}[a|p]m'}}]
matcher.add('TIME', None, pattern)

doc = nlp(text)
matches = matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    matched_span = doc[start:end]
    print(matched_span.sent.text)
```

Does that mean we can't use *normal* regex with spaCy? If so, do you know where I can learn the *special* regex syntax of spaCy? Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI: the "normal" regex can be just `regex = r'\d[ap]m'`.

Comment: You seem to be using it wrong per the docs: "When using the `REGEX` operator, keep in mind that it operates on **single tokens**, not the whole text. Each expression you provide will be matched on a token. If you need to match on the whole text instead, see the details on [regex matching on the whole text](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex-text)."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Although you are technically correct, it is a correction of a most likely incorrect regex because it is excluding 11 and 12 am/pm

Comment: Thanks, @MonkeyZeus. At first I was confused not understanding what you meant by `single token, not the the whole text` because I thought 6am, 6pm etc were single tokens. Only when reading Wiktor's answer I realised that spaCy treated them as 2 instead of 1 token. I wonder why spaCy does that because it seems not `natural` to me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that numbers will be separated from the letters here, see the test:

```
doc = nlp("1pm")
print([token.text for token in doc]) # => ['1', 'pm']
```

As per [Spacy docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching):

> If spaCy’s tokenization doesn’t match the tokens defined in a pattern, the pattern is not going to produce any results.

You need to define your own entity using rule-based matching:

```
pattern = [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'LOWER': {'REGEX' : '^[ap]m$'}}]
```

Then add it to matcher:

```
matcher.add('TIME', None, pattern)
```

And get the matches:

```
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(span.text)
```

Full demo:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = 'Monday to Friday 12 midnight to 5am 30% . Midnight Friday to 6am Saturday 30% . 9pm Saturday to Midnight Saturday 25% . Midnight Saturday to 6am Sunday 100% . 6am Sunday to 9pm Sunday 50%'
doc = nlp(text)

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'LIKE_NUM': True}, {'LOWER': {'REGEX' : '^[ap]m$'}}]
matcher.add('TIME', None, pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)
print([doc[start:end] for match_id, start, end in matches])
#=> [5am, 6am, 9pm, 6am, 6am, 9pm]
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you for not only providing the solution, but also showing me how to troubleshoot the issue next time. Your help is much appreciated. Regex is a challenge by itself (not only for me but many other people I guess), then combining it with spaCy is out of my league! Say if you want to match patterns, which would you use: regex or spaCy, and the reason why?

Comment: @Nemo Spacy is much more powerful than regex alone, so it all depends on what you need. If you need to extract, replace, remove or tag some known more or less simple patterns  you may use regex. If you need more specific and language aware tokenization and you need the whole power of NLP you should go on with Spacy.